# String formatting issues and concatenating a string with a number

Tags: python, formatting

I'm coming from a c# background, and I do this:

```
Console.Write("some text" + integerValue);
```

So the integer automatically gets converted to a string and it outputs.

In python I get an error when I do:

```
print 'hello' + 10
```

Do I have to convert to string everytime?

How would I do this in python?

```
String.Format("www.someurl.com/{0}/blah.html", 100);
```

I'm beginning to really like python, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> "www.someurl.com/{0}/blah.html".format(100)
'www.someurl.com/100/blah.html'
```

you can skip `0` in python 2.7 or 3.1.

Answer (score 4):

From Python 2.6:

```
>>> "www.someurl.com/{0}/blah.html".format(100)
'www.someurl.com/100/blah.html'
```

To support older environments, the `%` operator has a similar role:

```
>>> "www.someurl.com/%d/blah.html" % 100
'www.someurl.com/100/blah.html'
```

If you would like to support named arguments, then you can can pass a `dict`.

```
>>> url_args = {'num' : 100 }
>>> "www.someurl.com/%(num)d/blah.html" % url_args
'www.someurl.com/100/blah.html'
```

In general, when types need to be mixed, I recommend string formatting:

```
>>> '%d: %s' % (1, 'string formatting',)
'1:  string formatting'
```

String formatting coerces objects into strings by using their `__str__` methods.[*] There is much more detailed documentation available on Python string formatting in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). This behaviour is different in Python 3+, as all strings are unicode.

If you have a list or tuple of strings, the `join` method is quite convenient. It applies a separator between all elements of the iterable.

```
>>> ' '.join(['2:', 'list', 'of', 'strings'])
'2: list of strings'
```

If you are ever in an environment where you need to support a legacy environment, (e.g. Python <2.5), you should generally avoid string concatenation. See the article referenced in the comments.

[*] Unicode strings use the `__unicode__` method.

```
>>> u'3: %s' % ':)'
u'3: :)'
```

Comment: string concatenation is not frowned upon in Python.

Comment: Thanks @SilentGhost, will amend my post. I've only ever heard people tell me to avoid it. However http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#StringConcatenation seems to suggest it's not as evil as I've been told...

Comment: The `%` operator is in the process of being deprecated in favor of the `format` method (whose syntax is, BTW, very similar to the corresponding .NET syntax).

Comment: Strings are immutable in .NET and Java, too, so the issue of possibly quadratic behavior of string concatenations arises in these systems as well. However, the JIT compilers are very good at recognizing such patterns and replacing them by `StringBuilder` calls. A simple concatenation such as `'hello' + 10` is never going to be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to string formatting, you can always print like this:

```
print "hello", 10
```

Works since those are separate arguments and print converts non-string arguments to strings (and inserts a space in between).

Answer (score 1):

For string formatting that includes different types of values, use the % to insert the value into a string:

```
>>> intvalu = 10
>>> print "hello %i"%intvalu
hello 10
>>>
```

so in your example:

```
>>>print "www.someurl.com/%i/blah.html"%100
www.someurl.com/100/blah.html
```

In this example I'm using %i as the stand-in.  This changes depending on what variable type you need to use.  %s would be for strings.  There is a list [here on the python docs website](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).